# how to implement zxing barcode reader in Flex 4.5 mobile development.

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, zxing, flex-mobile

does anyone know how to implement the zxing barcode reader in Flex 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something more recent, there's a great step-by-step guide here:

http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-a-qr-code-reader-in-flex-on-android

For a downloadable fxp and apk (but less guidance) also try the following:

http://codeknow.blogspot.com/2011/04/quick-reader-flex4-xzing-android-air-26.html

This should be all you need to implement a barcode reader in Flex 4.5; hope you find it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of Flash Components available for that; just Google barcode reader Flash or Barcode Reader Flex.

Here is one from Renaun, an Adobe Evangelist:  http://renaun.com/flex2/BarcodeReader/BarcodeReader.html

The source link doesn't work, but here is the blog post on it: 
http://renaun.com/blog/2006/05/my-derby-submission-flex-barcode-reader/